# How to add text into a QR-Code?

Tags: positioning, pstricks, textpos, pst-barcode, barcodes

I want to add a text to the QR-Code. I want a small numbers in one of the four black squares.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, parskip]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
  \section{Demo}
  \begin{pspicture}(1.378in, 1.5in)
    \psbarcode[]{1}{height=1.378 width=1.378}{qrcode}
    {\color{white}1}
  \end{pspicture}
  \begin{pspicture}(1.378in, 1.5in)
    \psbarcode[]{2}{height=1.378 width=1.378}{qrcode}
    {\color{white}2}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I tried `textpos` with no success. Has somebody other ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `\rput(<x>,<y>){<stuff>}` to place `<stuff>` at coordinates (`<x>`,`<y>`):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, parskip]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
  \begin{pspicture}(1.378in, 1.5in)
    \psbarcode[]{1}{height=1.378 width=1.378}{qrcode}
    {\psset{unit=1.378in}\rput(0.165,0.165){\color{white}1}}
  \end{pspicture}
  \begin{pspicture}(1.378in, 1.5in)
    \psbarcode[]{2}{height=1.378 width=1.378}{qrcode}
    {\psset{unit=1.378in}\rput(0.835,0.835){\color{white}2}}
  \end{pspicture}
  \begin{pspicture}(1.378in, 1.5in)
    \psbarcode[]{2}{height=1.378 width=1.378}{qrcode}
    {\psset{unit=1.378in}\rput(0.165,0.835){\color{white}3}}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{document}​
```

I've used `\psset{unit=1.378in}` (short for `\psset{xunit=1.378in,yunit=1.378in}`) to make each `<x>` and `<y>` unit be equivalent to `1.378in`. That way, if you use `0`, you're at the left-most/bottom of the QR code, and `1` will bring you to the right-most/top of the QR code, since the QR code is square.