# Including a centered icon into a QR code

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, qrcode

Some people like having a icon in the centre of their QR code...
I want to use the [QRCode library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203487/14470) to produce such a QR code.

[image: qrcode with icon]

For now, I'm using

```
\documentclass[landscape,8pt]{minimal}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[]{qrcode}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{keepaspectratio}
\begin{document}
\topskip0pt
% https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Barcode-Contents
\centering\noindent\resizebox*\textwidth\textheight{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}%
%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2mm]
\node (qrc) {\qrcode[]{WIFI:T:WPA;S:trololol;P:"12345678";;}};
\node [anchor=center,fill=white,inner sep=4pt,scale=0.02] 
    (icon) at (qrc.center) {\includegraphics{wifi}};
\end{tikzpicture}
%
%
\end{tabular}%
\\%
\centering 12345678
\end{varwidth}}
\end{document}
```

to generate it, but it feels a bit weird, having to scale the icon manually. Also, I'm guessing that if the icon is big enough, the error recovery capabilities of the qrcode need to be adapted.

Is there any more convenient way of including such a centrally placed icon?

Comment: Can you give full code starting from `\documentclass` and ending at `\end{document}`?

Comment: As far as I know, the icon needs to be always taken into account whhen computing the QR code.

Comment: possibly related: [How to add text into a QR-Code?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37464/579)

Comment: Not related, but you should read: [why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Labels` can be added at `center` of nodes. You can use this option instead of an independent node.

```
\documentclass[landscape,8pt]{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[]{qrcode}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkeys{Gin}{keepaspectratio}
\begin{document}
\topskip0pt
% https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Barcode-Contents
\centering\noindent\resizebox*\textwidth\textheight{\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}%
%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2mm]
\node[label={[anchor=center, fill=white, scale=0.02]center:{\includegraphics{wifi}}}] (qrc) {\qrcode[]{WIFI:T:WPA;S:trololol;P:"12345678";;}};
\end{tikzpicture}
%
%
\end{tabular}%
\\%
\centering 12345678
\end{varwidth}}
\end{document}
```

[image]